# FLEX - Is it possible to override the default form item label font weight from bold to normal?

Tags: css, apache-flex

I am trying to un-bold the label in a form item. As you can see the label reacts to color change programmatically, but is un affected by a change to the fontWeight property. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thank You.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

        <fx:Style>
            @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
            @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
            global {
                font-family: Verdana;
                fontWeight: normal;
            }

            s|Label#labelDisplay {
                color: red;
                fontWeight:normal;
            }
        </fx:Style>

    <s:Form>
        <s:FormItem label="Please enter a string:" fontWeight="normal">
            <s:TextInput/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the fontWeight style directly on the labelDisplay Skin Part of the [FormItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/FormItem.html#SkinPartSummary).  You'll have to do it in ActionScript probably.  Try something like this:

```
<s:FormItem id="stringLabel" label="Please enter a string:" creationComplete="{stringLabel.labelDisplay.setStyle('fontWeight','normal'}" >
```

Since FormItem is just a SkinnableContainer; I am not surprised that fontWeight had no affect; however it is frustrating that the style did not pass onto the label child.

Comment: Ahh... Many thanks. I was trying to avoid re-skinning. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: instead of having to put an id for each FormItem you can put 'creationComplete="{event.currentTarget.labelDisplay.setStyle('fontWeight','normal')'